# Does snowfalke locks tables while a select is running?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I was trying to find the answer to this question in the docs, but could not.

Scenario:

```
Person A runs a SELECT on a large table. The query will run for a 30 seconds, for example.
Person B runs a TRUNCATE on the said table ten seconds later.
```

My question is: because **Person A** ran a `SELECT` query before **Person B's** `TRUNCATE` is ran, is the table *locked* by **Person A?** Meaning, will **Person A** get the data, and then the `TRUNCATE` of **Person B** execute?

Comment: I think select doesnt create any lock. But insert/update/delete does. So, instead of select if someone runs udpate and which takes longer than truncate, the truncate will wait or fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you truncate a table or perform any DML operation that deletes micropartitions, the micropartitions required for any running query will remain for at least the duration of those queries. Since that's happens, there's no need to lock for a select. Other than transient tables with 0 set for the retention period and temporary tables, the micropartitions that were deleted by a truncate or DML operation will remain for the duration of the Time Travel retention period (1 to 90 days) plus 7 days for failsafe.

Comment: Hi, @Greg, thank you for that. So what you're saying is that while select query is running, the truncate will not effect the result set of the said select query?

Comment: That's correct. You can try it yourself using an X-Small warehouse to select all rows from a large table and (if you're in one of the Snowflake web UIs) change to another tab and truncate the table. The one that started before the truncation will continue until it returns all rows that were in the table before the truncation. You can also run a select from the tab you used to truncate the table and it will return zero rows even while the other tab (that started a select before the truncate) is still reading rows.